# window manager other than compiz

Tags: compiz

How do I find out what my window manager is if it isnt compiz? the reason I ask is because im trying to track down the workspace switcher and Im pretty sure thats from compiz but when I try to reun compiz from the terminal it says I alredy have a window manager

Comment: When you start compiz from the terminal, use the `--replace` switch. If there's already another WM running (no matter if compiz or sth. else), a new WM instance can't be started. The `--replace` switch stops the running WM and starts the new WM instead.

Answer (score 0):

Install `wmctrl` and then run `wmctrl -m`. According to the **man** page:

```
   -m     Display information about the window manager and the environment.
```

For my system, I see:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: Openbox
Class: 
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
$
```